# Target class [PruebaController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy teniendo un error al querer genera la ruta a cualquier controlador.

Hice un nuevo proyecto con el comando laravel new proyecto y luego genere un modelo  de prueba con el comando:

```
php artisan make:model modelo -a
```

Con el parametro `-a` para que genere controlador migraciones entre otros.

Luego voy al `routes/web.php` y agrego lo siguiente:

[image: Route::get('/home', [PruebaController::class, 'index']);]

y al ejecutar

```
php artisa route:list
```

me da el error

> Target class [PruebaController] does not exist

Comment: En cierta manera hubieron algunos cambios como la erutación en Laravel 8, te recomiendo leer la documentación o las novedades que trae

Comment: Yo lo resolvi revisando esto revisa https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFvq8Dj21ZM

Answer (score 6):

Desde Laravel 8 vas a necesitar:

- Importar el namespace completo del controller que deseas usar
- Deberás (*para tu caso*) seguir la sintaxis de: **`[AlgoController::class, 'metodo']`**

Quedando de esta forma entonces:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PruebaController;
```

Y tu ruta queda así:

```
Route::get('/algo', [PruebaController::class, 'index']);
```

Lo anterior se debe a los cambios hechos en el *RouteServiceProvider.php*, que puedes navegar [aquí](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) para esta versión.

**Referencia**

- [Enrutamiento básico](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing)

Comment: Gracias anduvo!

Answer (score 4):

Al declarar tus rutas de esa manera, debes verificar que tengas incluido ese controlador en tu archivo. Por ende, al parecer no has incluido tu controlador:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PruebaController;

Route::get('/home', [PruebaController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes de agregar el `namespace` completo del controlador en el archivo web.php

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PruebaController; //<--- Controlador

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [PruebaController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para seguir utilizando como antes puedes descomentar o agregar en:
\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Antes de la línea

```
public function boot()
```

Quedaría así:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
public function boot()
{
...
```

Con esto ya puedes agregar las rutas como se manejaba anteriormente