# La clase de destino [HomeController] no existe

Tags: php, laravel

tengo el siguiente error al crear un controlador en laravel, ya habiéndolo creado en con la consola y editado me da el siguiente error:
**Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
La clase de destino [HomeController] no existe.**
El código de el controlador es:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

y el de la ruta:
`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`

gracias!!

Comment: La ultima versión que es la 8.0 si no me equivoco... lo que me sale en el composer.json es: "laravel/framework": "^8.0"

Comment: ¿Esto responde a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388577/target-class-pruebacontroller-does-not-exist/388596?r=SearchResults#388596

Comment: Voy a revisarlo, gracias

Comment: Ya lo vi y me funcionó correctamente, gracias!! Lo que si quería saber si el use App\Http\Controllers\PruebaController; se tiene que colocar siempre que haga un controller nuevo??

Comment: Checa bien la doc. Ahí te indica las prácticas a seguir para invocar controladores

Comment: Ok gracias...como te doy e el +1?? o no puedo? es que es la primera pregunta que hago