# ¿Por que laravel no encuentra el controlador?

Tags: laravel, controller

en la clase route.php o web.php mi caso pongo lo siguiente

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home','uses' => 'PagesController@home']);
```

cuando voy al navegador me dice

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [PagesController] does not exist.
```

---

cree el controlador con `php artisan make:controller` y me dice que no la encuentra

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Comment: Usas Laravel 8?

Comment: ¿Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388577/target-class-pruebacontroller-does-not-exist/388596#388596) tu duda?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Target class \[PruebaController\] does not exist](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388577/target-class-pruebacontroller-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No uso tu misma sintaxis para las rutas, *me parece enrevesada.*
Normalmente la escribiría como:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home')->name('home');
```

Puedes comprobar si la llamada entra a una ruta así:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    dd(111);
})->name('home');
```

En tu caso, no sería este el problema.

**Laravel 5.x**,**6** (última LTS) y **7**

En versiones antiguas, no aparece el problema que mencionas a menos que anides los controladores, con lo que hay que ajustar el namespace en las rutas, así un controlador con el namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Foo` requiere que se lo indiquemos en la ruta, por ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/', 'Foo\PagesController@home')->name('home');
```

**Laravel 8**

Ha cambiado la forma de trabajar con namespaces en algunos "partes", como las rutas.
Si antes los namespaces en las rutas partían de `App\Http\Controllers` ahora hay que indicarlos completos para que se "encuentre" la clase, por ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@home')->name('home');
```

creo que resuelve tu caso.

***Nota:** usa sentencias `use` en la cabecera de tu fichero de rutas con los controladores que usas ya que normalmente vas a llamar multiples veces a cada controlador.*

Aquí hay un [artículo con mas detalles sobre las rutas en Laravel 8](https://www.cursosdesarrolloweb.es/blog/namespaces-en-las-rutas-de-laravel-8/).

Comment: Hubiera sido mejor votar como duplicado (*en caso de que si use laravel 8*), pues la misma duda ya fue publicada como expongo en los comentarios

Comment: @BetaM no lo he visto. Pero no esta de más indicar *explicitamente* las diferencias entre versiones, seguimos trabajando con las antiguas.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, está comentada la siguiente línea:

`//protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';`

La debes habilitar o descomentar en la siguiente ruta
`app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`