# Target class [CategoriaController] does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola buenos dias tengo este link quiero que lleve al documento categoria

```
<a href="{{url('productos/categoria')}}">Empresa</a>
```

Este es mi ruta

```
Route::get('/categoria','CategoriaController@categoria')->name('categoria');
```

Este es mi controlador

```
 public function categoria()
{
    //
    return redirect('categoria');
    
}
```

pero al darle click en el link me manda a la pagina pero en blanco

[image: Esta es la carpeta]

Comment: Target class [CategoriaController] does not exist. ahora me sale esto me puedes ayudar

Comment: es laravel 8 esa es mi version

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Target class \[PruebaController\] does not exist](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388577/target-class-pruebacontroller-does-not-exist)

Comment: no amigo aun no

Comment: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController] does not exist.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca como texto el código de como quedó la llamada a tu controlador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo hay a algunas cosas que no están del todo claras. Por ejemplo, el tag del link apunta a 'productos/categoria', la ruta a 'categoria' y el controlador a 'categoria'. Si quieres que te lleve al documento 'categoria', debería devolver una vista en vez de un redirect.

Si le va a dar nombre a las rutas, le conviene usar el link de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="{{ route('categoria') }}">Empresa</a>
```

Ese link le pegará a la ruta que tienes declarada como:

```
Route::get('/categoria','CategoriaController@categoria')->name('categoria');
```

No sé que versión de Laravel estés usando, pero en la 8 la forma correcta de declarar la ruta es:

```
Route::get('/categoria', [\App\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController::class, 'categoria'])->name('categoria');
```

Eso llamará a tu función 'categoria' del controlador. En esa función si quieres ver un archivo blade, tienes que devolverlo. Como la vista de 'categoria' está anidada dentro de la carpeta productos, debes indicarla con el punto:

```
return view('productos.categoria');
```

Así, te debería funcionar correctamente.